# 504 Gateway Timeout (Gunicorn-Django-Nginx) Docker Compose Problem

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

There is one process backend which take around 1-2 minutes to process. The loading screen runs for 1 minute and shows 504 Gateway Timeout

Here's the log in nginx.access.log

```
172.18.0.2 - - [16/Dec/2022:23:54:02 +0000] "POST /some_request HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://localhost/some_url" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

But from the django debug log, I can see that the POST request is still processing at the backend

docker-compose.yml
timeout is set to 300, without it, the browser will return 502 error (connection prematurely closed)

```
services:
  web:
    image: genetic_ark_web:2.0.0
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn ga_core.wsgi:application --bind :8000 --timeout 300 --workers 2 --threads 4"
```

This is all the params I have tried in nginx.conf but still the 504 timeout is returned after 60s

```
server {

    # port to serve the site
    listen 80;

    # optional server_name
    server_name untitled_name;
    ...

    # request timed out -- default 60
    client_body_timeout 300;
    client_header_timeout 300;

    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 300;

    # server will close connection after this time -- default 75
    keepalive_timeout 300;

    location /url_pathway/ {
        proxy_pass          http://ga;

        # header
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;

        proxy_redirect      off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout    300s;
        proxy_read_timeout    300s;
        send_timeout          300s;
        keepalive_timeout     300s;
        
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
        
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
        uwsgi_connect_timeout 300s;
```

Any idea which parameter might be controlling the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not caused by nginx-container or web-container.
Fixed by changing timeout in nginx-proxy which is timing out causing 499 error in nginx access log while web container is continuing its backend process

Added below in nginx.conf for nginx-container

```
proxy_read_timeout    300s;
```

For nginx-proxy, `proxy_read_timeout    300s;` is added to the config too